# i got ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

my data set is '[kc_house_data_NaN.csv](https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DA0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/FinalModule_Coursera/data/kc_house_data_NaN.csv)'

**question)** Fit a linear regression model to predict the 'price' using the list of features:

```
"floors"
"waterfront"
"lat"
"bedrooms"
"sqft_basement"
"view"
"bathrooms"
"sqft_living15"
"sqft_above"
"grade"
"sqft_living"
```

The calculate the R^2. Take a screenshot of your code and the value of the R^2.
**code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
features =["floors", "waterfront","lat" ,"bedrooms" ,"sqft_basement" ,"view" ,"bathrooms","sqft_living15","sqft_above","grade","sqft_living"]
X = df[["floors", "waterfront","lat" ,"bedrooms" ,"sqft_basement" ,"view" ,"bathrooms","sqft_living15","sqft_above","grade","sqft_living"]]
Y = df['price']
lm2 = LinearRegression()
lm2
lm2.fit(X,Y)
lm2.score(X, Y)
```

**error:**

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)

 58 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

where is the actual wrong in coding

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code from what I can see, but you need to do data pre-processing to get rid of NaN values. You might need to either remove NaNs are fill them with some other value.

Comment: Hold on, I don't see you loading the csv anywhere...

Comment: pavel, the csk file is at the top

Comment: "NaN" in filename immediately clues to the fact that it has NaNs aplenty unless you renamed it to this.